Updating a view with an observedobject from fetchedresults core data
I have a parent view that is reading from core data and creating a list of child node information. I would like for each row to be updated as soon as a value is updated.
My first attempt, I used fetchedresults to make a list and pass an @Observedobject to another view to render the row. It kind of worked but only updated the view when you switched back and forth to a different UI tab, not on the spot.
My second attempt, I used a NotificationCenter.default.publisher and a @State variable refreshID = UUID on the List and NodeListItem. This worked on re-rendering the views, but the .onReceive function gets called about 8-9 times for every row item and every minute when peripheral receives passive data, and it also dismisses a sheet view for updating the user row whenever the peripheral sends a text message notification
NodeList
  struct NodeList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @EnvironmentObject var bleManager: BLEManager
    @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "user.vip", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastHeard", ascending: false)], animation: .default)

    var nodes: FetchedResults<RadioInfoEntity>

    private var didSave =  NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave)
    @State private var refreshID = UUID()

     var body: some View {
       NavigationStack (path: $path) {
        List(nodes, id: \.self) { node in
         NodeListItem(node: node,
                     connected: bleManager.connectedPeripheral != nil && bleManager.connectedPeripheral?.num ?? -1 == node.num)
        .onReceive(self.didSave) { _ in   //the listener
                        self.refreshID = UUID()
                        print("generated a new UUID")
                        }
        }.id(refreshID)
        .onAppear {
          if self.bleManager.context == nil {
          self.bleManager.context = context
            }
        }
      }
     }
   }

NodeListItem
struct NodeListItem: View {

  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
  @EnvironmentObject var bleManager: BLEManager
  @ObservedObject var node: RadioInfoEntity
  @State private var name: String = ""

  var body: some View { 
   LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
     Text(name)
     let status = getStatus(status: name)
     Text(status)
     Button("Update") {
        showingSheetView.toggle()
              } .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheetView) {
                SheetView(user: node)
            }
     }.onAppear(perform: {
        if let tempName = node.user?.name{
          self.name = tempName
       }
      })
     }
   }


struct SheetView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var SheetViewDismiss
  @ObservedObject var user: RadioInfoEntity
  @State private var name: String = ""
  var body: some View {
     HStack{
      TextField("name", text: $customName)
     }
     .onAppear(perform: {
         self.longName = user.user?.name ?? ""
       })
      Button("Update") {
        self.user.objectWillChange.send()
        var u = User()
        //this is a longer function in reality
        u.name = getUpdatedName(name: name)
        bleManager.saveUser(config: u, fromUser: connectedUser, toUser: user.user!)
        SheetViewDismiss()
        }
     }
   }
 }

BLEmanager works a bit something like this
 class BLEManager: NSObject, CBPeripheralDelegate, ObservableObject {

   // MARK: Data Read / Update Characteristic Event
   func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case FROMRADIO_UUID:
     switch decodedInfo.packet.decoded.portnum {
      case .nodeinfoApp:
      upsertNodeInfoPacket(packet: decodedInfo.packet, context: context!)
      }
     }
  }
 }

UpdateCoreData
  func upsertNodeInfoPacket (packet: MeshPacket, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
   let fetchNodeInfoAppRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "RadioInfoEntity")
        fetchNodeInfoAppRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "num == %lld", Int64(packet.from))
   do {
    let fetchedRadio = try context.fetch(fetchNodeInfoAppRequest) as? [RadioInfoEntity] ?? []
     fetchedRadio[0].id = Int64(packet.from)
     fetchedRadio[0].num = Int64(packet.from)
     fetchedRadio[0].lastHeard = Date()
     if let nodeInfoMessage = try? NodeInfo(serializedData: packet.decoded.payload) {
      if nodeInfoMessage.hasUser {
       fetchedRadio[0].user!.userId = nodeInfoMessage.user.id
       fetchedRadio[0].user!.num = Int64(nodeInfoMessage.num)
       fetchedRadio[0].user!.name = nodeInfoMessage.user.name
      }
     }
     do {
           //this was never needed or seen to do anything so commented out
      //fetchedRadio[0].objectWillChange.send()
       try context.save()
       print(" Updated NodeInfo from Node Info App Packet For: \(fetchedRadio[0].num)")
       } catch {
            context.rollback()
            let nsError = error as NSError
           print(" Error Saving RadioInfoEntity from NODEINFO_APP \(nsError)")
        }
        } catch {
          print(" Error Fetching RadioInfoEntity for NODEINFO_APP")
        }
}
     
     

Any suggestions would be really appreciated

I would suggest, to move all the data logic into one dedicated object (conforming to ObservableObject, which also publishes a value type which represents your view state. That is, it internally uses the CoreData context and the CBPeripheralDelegate to execute logic and composes the view state. Your view does nothing than just rendering the view state.

You need to remove the @State and use the @ObservedObject as follows:
@ObservedObject var node: RadioInfoEntity
...
Text(node.name)


I wish it were that simple but I am taking each name and checking for a delimiter and only showing the first component. Unwrapping this optional also complicates things and throws errors if not done correctly

You can use computed property to transform from model data to view data. Optionals are easy to transform with ?? syntax
